# Can I use Git's ignore processing outside of Git?

Tags: git

- `git` is installed
- I have a directory that contains some directories and files, this is NOT a Git repository
- I have a Git ignore file which specifies some file inclusions and exclusions

Is it possible for me to use one of the `git` command line tools to recursively list the files in the directory, based on the exclusion rules in the ignore file?

Answer (score 2):

You could temporarily init it as a git repository and delete the .git directory when done.

Comment: You don't have to have the git directory there, even.  ```(export GIT_DIR=`mktemp -dt`; git init $GIT_DIR; git ls-files --o --exclude-standard)```. I have a global alias `git config --global alias.ls "ls-files --exclude-standard"`. Also note that you can feed `git ls-files` alternate exclude sets in many ways.